# Separate file for Environment Variable - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have this environment variable file that exports variable config depending on the NODE_END. Currently production and development variable are residing inside a one file, code below. How can I separate the file like development.js and production.js:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports = {
        API_URL: "https://test.co/api"
    }
}
else {
    module.exports = {
        API_URL: "http://testbeta.co/api"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a separate file to bridge them and export the intended module. For example, make three separate files `index.js`, `development.js`, and `production.js` on the same folder `api`.

```
// production.js
module.exports = {
    API_URL: "https://e27.co/api"
}

// development.js
module.exports = {
     API_URL: "http://e27beta.co/api"  
}

// index.js
let exp
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    exp = require('./production.js')
} else {
    exp = require('./development.js')
}
module.exports = exp
```

Then you can require it elsewhere like

```
// elsewhere.js
const api = require('path_to_api_folder')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using Webpack you can leverage the DefinePlugin plugin for exactly this purpose:

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/#use-case-service-urls

```
if(isProd) {
  config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'SERVICE_URL': JSON.stringify("http://prod.example.com")
  }));
} else {
  config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'SERVICE_URL': JSON.stringify("http://dev.example.com")
  }));
}
```

Comment: I se the webpackDefinePlugin for 'process.env.NODE_ENV', I just want to put it in a separate file not in webpack.config.js

Comment: just import a config file into your webpack file using normal require/import

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2 separate webpack configs, each with the appropriate SERVICE_URL'S.

```
// webpack.config.dev.js
plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'SERVICE_URL': JSON.stringify("http://dev-url.com")
}));

// webpack.config.prod.js
plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'SERVICE_URL': JSON.stringify("http://prod-url.com")
}));
```

To build, just pass webpack the appropriate config:

```
webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js
webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js
```